# Conan Add remote Task in Azure Pipelines : Failing when adding two remotes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifactory, conan

I have a Azure DevOps pipeline in which I am adding two remotes. When using the [JFrog Extension](https://jfrog.com/blog/accelerate-azure-devops-or-tfs-with-jfrog-artifactory-and-conan/) for  Azure Pipelines and the included conan upload task, this task will not use the configured remote, but always the last added. Is there any solution to this or what am I  missing?

I hope the following describes the setup well enough:

## Service connections / repos:

### Prerelease Repo

Service  connection with technical user to  add,update,delete pre released packages (typically branch based releases)

```
 - task: ArtifactoryConan@1
   displayName: "Add conan develop remote"
   inputs:
     conanCommand: "Add Remote"
     remoteName: "develop"
     artifactoryService: "Artifactory_Develop"
     conanRepo: "develop"
     purgeExistingRemotes: false
     conanUserHome: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
```

### Release repo

Service connection with a restricted technical user to only add to a release repo, but not update or delete

```
 - task: ArtifactoryConan@1
   displayName: "Add conan release remote"
   inputs:
     conanCommand: "Add Remote"
     remoteName: "release"
     artifactoryService: "Artifactory_Release"
     conanRepo: "release"
     purgeExistingRemotes: false
     conanUserHome: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
```

## Upload task

Based on branches, I would like to upload and publish my Conan artifacts to the dedicated repository, using the dedicated  service connection:

```
- task: ArtifactoryConan@1
        displayName: "Conan upload develop repo"
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
        inputs:
          conanCommand: "Upload"
          remoteName: "develop"
          patternOrReference: "$(conan_package_name)/$(conan_package_version)@$(project_name)/$(conan_channel)"
          extraArguments: "--all -c"
          buildName: "$(Build.DefinitionName)"
          buildNumber: "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
          conanUserHome: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
```

## Result

The conan upload task seems to be always using the last added remote?

```
2020-06-02T10:43:03.3661883Z ##[section]Starting: Conan upload develop repo
2020-06-02T10:43:03.3669805Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-02T10:43:03.3670263Z Task         : Artifactory Conan
2020-06-02T10:43:03.3670628Z Description  : This task runs a Conan command.
2020-06-02T10:43:03.3670974Z Version      : 1.9.4
2020-06-02T10:43:03.3671273Z Author       : JFrog
2020-06-02T10:43:03.3671597Z Help         : Run Conan command.
2020-06-02T10:43:03.3671999Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-02T10:43:03.8219651Z Running Conan build tool from: /usr/local/bin/conan
2020-06-02T10:43:03.8220128Z Conan User Home: /__w/1
2020-06-02T10:43:03.8245768Z Running Conan command at: /__w/1/s
2020-06-02T10:43:03.8257251Z [command]/usr/local/bin/conan upload --all -c HelloWorld/1.0@Hello/develop
2020-06-02T10:43:04.2091929Z Uploading to remote 'release':
2020-06-02T10:43:04.2165470Z 
2020-06-02T10:43:04.2166636Z Uploading HelloWorld/1.0@Hello/develop to remote 'release'
```

Comment: If you don't pass a specific remote, Conan will upload to the first remote in the list. I do recommend passing `-r <remote_name>` to avoid any mistake. When I say the first in the list, it's about the index, not age. If you want to add a new remote as first in the list, you must pass `--insert`. Take a look on docs: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/remote.html

Comment: Yes, as shown in the "Upload task", the remote is given with the "remoteName" attribute. I would like to  use it  the way it is intended for the  pipeline, because in this way I can map service connections ( to obfuscate and securely store the credentials) towards the remotes. Also I think this is a bug.

Comment: UNderstood, now trying to set the remote in the "extra arguments" option. Anyhow not sure, why the "remoteName" is not working..

Comment: I didn't understand your comment, because your log shows: "[command]/usr/local/bin/conan upload --all -c HelloWorld/1.0@Hello/develop". There is no remote listed there. As you are running it for CI job, you can use CONAN_REMOTE environment variable instead.

Comment: Is it working if you set the remote in the "extra arguments" option?  You can report the `remoteName` attribute not working issue [here](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-azure-devops-extension/issues)

Comment: @uilianries Yes, but it is not called from the shell, I am using the yaml declaration for azure devops pipelines and the extensino from jfrog has a problem there.

Comment: thx @LeviLu-MSFT was not able to find a propper channel as jfrog are listing stackoverflow as their community...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the "-r (--remote) option in the "extraArguments", the correct remote was used:

```
- task: ArtifactoryConan@1
    displayName: "Conan upload develop repo"
    inputs:
      conanCommand: "Upload"
      remoteName: "MYREMOTE" # this is not working
      patternOrReference: "$(conan_package_name)/$(conan_package_version)@$(project_name)/$(conan_channel)"
      extraArguments: "--all -c -r MYREMOTE" # this is
      buildName: "$(Build.DefinitionName)"
      buildNumber: "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      conanUserHome: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
```

Comment: Also this is reported at https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-azure-devops-extension/issues/162